# How to minimize/maximize the Ribbon

Tags: wpf, ribbon, minimize, maximize

I use the Ribbon for WPF (2010 - `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`). I want to create a Button, which minimize or maximize the Ribbon Tab, like in msoffice this button:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just access the **IsMinimized** property of the ribbon to Minimize / Maximize.